# How to set a specific header in a single folder with Nginx?

Tags: nginx

I want to keep the exact same settings as below in all folders, except for one. In the folder /wp-admin the setting `add_header Cache-Control "no-store";` should be added *only* for .php files.

Question:
How to change a setting only in a specific folder in Nginx?

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi.conf;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
    access_log off;
}

location [IF PHP FILE IN wp-admin FOLDER] {
    add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
}

location ~* \.(js|css|svg|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|eot|otf|ttf|woff)$ {
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
    expires 1y;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any location block that processes PHP files needs to contain all of the fastcgi parameters and directives. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html) on request processing.

I have not tested this, but you should be able to use a `map` directive to select the appropriate value for the `add_header` statement.

For example:

```
map $request_uri $cc {
    ~^/wp-admin  "no-store";
    default      "public";
}

server {
    ...
    location ~ \.php$ {
        add_header Cache-Control $cc;
        ...
    }
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) for details.