# Issue with the NGINX directive add_headers

Tags: php, nginx

I am trying to setup a custom content secutiry policy depending on deirectory but my headers are not displaying to the browser.

This is what I initially tried (that did not work).

```
location / {
    add_header "Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only" "default-src 'self';";
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}

location /myfolder/ {
    add_header "Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only" "default-src 'self' data:;";
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php-fpm.sock;
}
```

Also tried adding the `add_header` directive inside the php location (alongside with many other combinations) but I could not find something that worked to solve my issue.

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php-fpm.sock;

    location / {
        add_header "Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only" "default-src 'self';";
    }

    location /myfolder/ {
        add_header "Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only" "default-src 'self' data:;";
    }
}
```

With just one `add_header` the issue would be easy to solve as it could be included in the php block (or outside the three of them) but I couldn't find a solution for the case I have when the headers must be set by directory.

Has anybody else had this problem? Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39356843/how-to-set-a-specific-header-in-a-single-folder-with-nginx/39357234#39357234).

Comment: Thank you very much Richard, that saved my day.